# How to make Google Sheets autowrite value into table

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to place some values in a table, given their row and column coordinates. Do I have to use a script or can I use a function?

On the image I swapped the x and y axis but I think you get the point.

[image: sample data]

Comment: Hello, could you post your custom script here? I would really appreciate it if you did! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I could think of four approaches.

1. Fill the sheet with single-cell `vlookup` formulas looking up values in that table for their row/column. Drawback: many lookups, most of which will be fruitless. The performance is likely to be poor.
2. Try to do (1) with an arrayformula. Drawback: I don't see how to implement that purely in Sheets logic.
3. Have a custom function returning an array. Drawback: a custom function can only return a rectangular array. The table would be non-editable directly, as an attempt to edit it would result in the output of custom function failing to expand.
4. A script triggered from the menu. This is what I did below.

The script adds a menu command "write a table". To use it, first select the range and then invoke the command.

```
function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Write a table", functionName: "write"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}

function write() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var inp = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(inp[i][0]+inp[i][1]);
    sheet.getRange(inp[i][0]+inp[i][1]).setValue(inp[i][2]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Create crosstab report using an array formula

Use the following formulas:

Cell B8 : Column Headers

```
=transpose($B$3:$B$5)
```

Cell A9 : Row Headers

```
={$A$3:$A5}
```

CELL B9 : cross tabbed values

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(vlookup({A9:A11&B8:D8},{A3:A5&B3:B5,C3:C5},2,0))))
```

## Explanation

- `{A9:A11&B8:D8}` creates an array of keys by joining the values of the X (row headers) and Y (column headers) columns.
  Note: As the first element is 3 X 1 array and the second is a 1 X 3 array, the result is a 3 X 3 array.
- `{A3:A5&B3:B5,C3:C5}` creates an array having two columns. The first column holds the keys and the second the values.
  Note: In the concatenation, the first element is a 3 x 1 array and the second also is a 3 x 1 array so the result is a 3 x 1 array.
- `vlookup` will return a value for each match and error for each cell without a match.
- `IFERROR` will replace errors by empty values.
- `ArrayFormula` extends the array of values to the required cells.